# Grid lines in top-view surface plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm almost satisfied with my graphs, only grid lines are missing. What I'm basically doing is a sort of density plot / color plot by letting pgfplots generate a surface and viewing it from the top:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = middle,
            grid = major,
            grid style = {color = white!90!black},
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            no markers,
            mesh/ordering=y varies,
            view={0}{90},
            colormap = {graywhite}{color=(white) color=(gray)},
        ]
        \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] file{surf.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Example output, using [this](http://pastebin.com/7jqVvA2Z) input:

[image: output]

The surface is drawn using a fine grid (50x50), thus leaving the original mesh lines is a no-go. By choosing `shader=interp` pgfplots basically removes the mesh lines and interpolates the colors nicely. It would be fantastic if some grid lines could be drawn on top of this, using e.g. black with 10% opacity. Does anyone how to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Arguably, if you use `view={0}{90}`, you don't need to plot in 3D. Use `addplot` instead of `addplot3` and the grid will be drawn as expected.

Comment: @Jubobs: Thank you for the warm welcome, unfortunately I cannot see how to produce such a color plot without a "fake" surface, care to explain?

Comment: Do you mean the *mesh* lines by grid lines? Grid lines are related to the axes.

Comment: @percusse: No really grid lines, they should cross the axes at the ticks.

Comment: It looks like a ghost!

Comment: @Bugbusters: It does indeed :) fyi it actually represents the uncertainty in a frequency response function (it's a sort of probability density measure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you are doing: `colormap = {graywhite}{color=(white) color=(gray)}` it fills the entire plotting area with white. So the grid lines are hidden behind your plot.

To plot them on top as you requested you could use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        grid = major,
        grid style = {color = white!90!black},
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        no markers,
        mesh/ordering=y varies,
        view={0}{90},
        colormap = {graywhite}{color=(white) color=(gray)},
    ]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] file{surf.txt};
    \draw[dotted,step={(axis cs:5,5)},help lines] (0,0) grid (axis cs:30,20);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produces:
[image: Result]

To plot black lines with 10% opacity you can use:
`\draw[opacity=0.1,step={(axis cs:5,5)}] (0,0) grid (axis cs:30,20);`

Comment: good idea! note that there is also an option `axis on top` which changes the layering in a way that the axis is drawn on top of the plots (in this case on top of the surface). This would probably also have the desired effect

Comment: Good suggestion Christian however upon trying `axis on top` doesn't seem to do the job... It would be nice to understand why though...

Comment: @vrleboss: Fantastic, it works like a charm!